# Laravel Mail Ignores my send from

Tags: email, laravel-5

So i'm trying to send a mail from a form using laravel, the email gets sent to the right address i specify, but the problem is, it ignores my `message->from('$request->sender_email','Sender name')` and always uses my gmail address as the sender
I have echoed the sender_email and it exists. 
It also sends the correct Sender Name too

Heres my controller method

```
public function insert_sendmail(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request,
    [

      'sender_email' => 'required',
      'receiver_email' => 'required',
      'receiver_name' => 'required',
      'message' => 'required'

    ]);
    $data = array('name'=>"$request->message");
    // dd($request);

   Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $data, function($message) use($request)
   {

      $message->to($request->receiver_email, $request->receiver_name)->subject('Basic Email Notification Testing Mail');
      $message->from("$request->sender_email",'Admin');
   });
  return redirect()->route('settings.index')->with('info', 'Email Sent');

}
```

Please help me spot anything i'm doing wrong

Comment: You're sending the email using your gmail account?

Comment: @StyleSh1t I used my gmail account in my .env file

Comment: @MattGibson lemme check it out

Comment: Try this $message->from($request->sender_email,'Admin');

The value of $request->sender_email should match the value of your gmail account

Comment: @mohit i know this. but i want the sender's email from to be dynamic. Meaning it uses the sender's email address that's been registered on my database as where the email is being sent from.

Comment: @MattGibson they did not actually answer the question there. Can you suggest any other method i can use to achieve what i want?

Comment: For that you will have to change the SMTP details i think you can't do that with Gmail sMTP

Comment: @mohit yes you cant do that with gmail. I'm currently setting up mailgun for that. I'd let you know if it works out

Comment: For anyone who runs into this issue, switch over to mailgun. They have lesser restrictions as compared to using gmail to setup your smtp.